# Swagger not working with Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger

I followed the instructions on the following page to add Swagger to my Spring MVC application
http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

But I am not able to get Swagger to work. Whenever I hit the following URL: 
http://localhost:8080/demoApp/swagger-ui.html

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpRequest(Lorg/springframework/http/HttpRequest;)Lorg/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder;
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1287)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I tried looking up many articles and also tried the xml configuration instead of the annotation one but no use. There is a similar question on SO that says there might be an issue with Spring version and upgrading to Spring 4 and above solves the problem but I am already using spring version 4.1.4

Here is my pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

This is how I have registered the swagger resources with the application

```
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

Comment: can you please post your pom file?

Comment: Share your controller class and swagger-config class

Comment: @hovanessyan Hello, I have updated the question with pom.xml

Comment: @Yogi Hello, I have added the config class to the question but not sure which controller are you asking me to post.

Comment: @NickDiv As your application is not springBoot application, have you registered Swagger's resources?

Comment: Yes I did that. Let me add that piece of config as well.

Comment: ok. When you start your application, do you see in the output messages from Spring mvc EndpointHandlerMapping related to swagger? (e.g. /swagger-resources/ , /swagger-resources/configuration/ui) ? What is your application root? Do you have any default api prefixes configured by default?

Comment: No, I do not see any Swagger end-points in the logs. But I am able to reach the Swagger UI. Just dont see the API calls listed. The page opens with stacktrace in the body. the root of the app is demoApp

Comment: I see - have you tried to clean and rebuild your project? (also it it's not a problem you can delete your local .m2 and build from the command line)

Comment: Yup. I tried that as well :(

Comment: If you are using Spring Security, use the security configuration mentioned on **[Cannot open Swagger UI in tis Version 3 in my Spring Boot Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73073519/cannot-open-swagger-ui-in-tis-version-3-in-my-spring-boot-example)** page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `spring-web` dependency is version 4.1.4, where [UriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) does not have the method swagger-ui is trying to invoke:

```
org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpRequest(Lorg/springframework/http/HttpRequest;)
```

You need to bump your Spring version to higher one (e.g. 4.3.5+). where this [method is availble](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html).

Comment: Damn that was genius. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use the annotations @EnableSwagger2

you have an easier way to add swagger.

you can find the solution by check my answer in the below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48206971/4374472

Here you will have to add some dependency in pom.xml and a maven plugin , which will do the job.