# How to use Swagger in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have made a basic CRUD app, wish to add Swagger with it.

My endpoints are -

`@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1")`

`GET - /get_all_bookings`

`POST - /new_booking`

`PUT - /update_booking/{id}`

`DELETE - /delete_booking/{id}`

So I Included the dependency `springfox-swagger2` & `springfox-swagger-ui`,
then a config package and inside it `SwaggerConfig` class,

```
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket postsApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("public-api")
                .apiInfo(apiInfo()).select().paths(postPaths()).build();
    }

    private Predicate<String> postPaths() {
        return or(regex("/api/v1/*"), regex("/api/v1/get_all_bookings*"));
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Demo API")
                .description("Placeholder")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("www.something.com")
                .contact("sandeep.roy2014@gmail.com").license("Free")
                .licenseUrl("www.somthing.com").version("1").build();
    }
}
```

It gives too many errors, which I'm not able to understand.

```
Error creating bean with name 'swagger2Controller': Lookup method resolution failed

Failed to introspect Class [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2aae9190]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

I'm not very sure, what exactly I'm doing wrong! Although all endpoints working fine when tried in Postman.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot 3 or above, the recommendation is to use springdoc. Please refer to the answer in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74614369/how-to-run-swagger-3-on-spring-boot-3.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have this dependency in your POM file

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
```